# How can I set drawtext fontsize in ffmpeg according to resolutions ratio

Tags: ffmpeg, scaling, drawtext

How can I set fontsize for drawtext on video according to width and height of each resolutions, to a certain proportion?

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=OpenSans-Regular.ttf: \
text='New Music Video': fontcolor=white: fontsize=?: r=25: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.3: \ boxborderw=3: x=(20)/2: y=(h-text_h-20) " Output.mp4
```

I ask this question because when I set it to 24 `fontsize=24` for example,it size is defferent at other resolutions,when convert is done.

Comment: `fontsize` doesn't support expressions yet, only integer values. Unless you want to patch it in, determine the required size and pass it to the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: The hack way to do this is to draw the text on a transparent BG and then use scale2ref to size the text and then overlay it.

Comment: @Mulvya Can you give me a sample code or any example?how can draw text on a transparent BG?

Comment: @Mulvya It seems cannot work as your mention,because when you change the size of Background,text size not changes.
And some characters of text fade out,because just BG box size decreased.

Comment: I'm busy with work now, so can supply a command later, but basic flow is 1)create transparent BG 2)draw text on BG 3)use scale2ref to resize BG w/ text.

Answer (score 8):

[Since ffmpeg version **3.4**](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/6442e4ab3cab573e6f86bfa6db096afd8edef453), video filter `drawtext` supports arithmetic expressions in its `fontsize` parameter. For example, height divided by 30:

```
-vf drawtext="fontsize=(h/30): x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h*2): text='Hello, World!': fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5"
```

This will use font size 24 on a 720p video and 36 on a 1080p video.

See also [more examples on how to use filter `drawtext` in ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1).

Answer (score 6):

I have been faced with this question too,here is my solution: **use various resolution's diagonal's rate , scale your textsize**.

Here is details:

1. Find a suitable textsize in your most used resolution. e.g. 
   textsize=65   in  resolution=1920*1080
2. Use target video's resolution's diagonal divide by 1920*1080's diagonal,then multiply by your suitable textsize (65),result is what you want

kotlin code here:

```
(Math.sqrt((videoWidth*videoWidth + videoHeight*videoHeight).toDouble()) / 2203 * textsize).toInt()
```

Comment: in this code 2203 is where from you found ?  @Rabbit

Comment: It's the diagonal dimension.